# Laravel eloquent Has Many Through relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

So, Here it is. I have 3 tables and the structure of them as follow:

```
**user**
 -id
 -name
 -password
 -etc...

**user_general_info**
 -id
 -the_user_id
 -country_id
 -phone
 -desc
 ...

**country**
 -id
 -name
```

For the obvious reason I have model for each 3 of them. Now How do I declare eloquent relationship between these 3 so I can get data of user's country (something like `$user->user_general_info->user_country->name`).? I already tried a `hasManyThrough`, but it didn't work out.

Do I have to add the `country` **foreign key** to the `user` table? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a user have multiple entries in `user_general_info`?

Comment: No. User can only have 1 entry in `user_general_info` table.

Comment: If a user could have multiple entries, a `BelongsToMany` relationship would have been the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this. However, one of the cleanest method is by declaring a `hasOne` relationship in your user model and retrieving the results.

So Suppose you have three models, `User`, `UserGeneralInfo` and `Country`. Go to your `User` model and declare the following.

```
 public function userGeneralInfo()
 {
     return $this->hasOne('App\UserGeneralInfo', 'user_id', 'id');
 }


 public function userCountry()
 {
     return $this->hasOne('App\Country', 'user_id', 'id');
 }
```

Now when querying use the following

```
$user = User:where('id, $id)->with('userGeneralInfo')->with('userCountry')->first();
```

This will give you the user along with its related general info and user country. Now you can access the variables using.

`$user->userGeneralInfo->phone` to retrieve the phone number. Similarly, `$user-> userCountry->name` to get the country name.

Note: There are multiple approaches to get your desired results, this one being and simplest amount them for starters to understand. You can learn more about the complex relationships [laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: What about the inverse relationship? I mean `country` can have many `user`. How could I get all `user` in a `country`? But only `user_general_info` have those 2 foreign key.